# Очистить таблицу от всех атрибутов, но оставить атрибут rowspan

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Нужно очистить таблицу от всех атрибутов, но оставить атрибут rowspan, который может быть (rowspan="2" или rowspan="3" и т.д.)

Написал код

```
$explanations =  preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$2$1>', $explanations);
```

но он очищает все атрибуты, как оставить только rowspan?

Comment: Нужно использовать [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php), правда регулярку раздует еще больше.

Comment: Доработал ответ:  

    http://ideone.com/wRdqeA - результат первой очистки
    http://ideone.com/jNHGlC - результат последующих очисток

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Посмотреть рабочий пример](http://ideone.com/wRdqeA)**

```
$string = '<td colspan="1" rowspan="4" style="padding:0px 3px 0px 3px;">';
$pattern = '/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)++(?:( rowspan="\d+")|(?:[^>]?(?=( rowspan="\d+")?))++)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i';

// Важное примечание: оставит только первое вхождение rowspan
$result = preg_replace($pattern, '<$1$2$3$4>', $string);
```

Comment: Спасибо, но мимо: 
Попробуйте вот эту переменную: 
$string = '<td style="padding:0px 3px 0px 3px;vertical-align:bottom;background-color:#fff2cc;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;border-right:;border-bottom:;">750</td>';

Comment: @MaXiM3006, обновил ответ. Теперь он работает на вашем примере

Comment: Очищает но убирает rowspan. Вот полная версия HTML таблицы, вставленный в пример:  http://ideone.com/4vJ1vZ

Comment: @MaXiM3006, теперь все работает, как надо. Исправил ошибки в основном выражении. Проблема была в квантификаторах. Обновил ответ и пример.

Comment: Браво! Работает идеально. Посоветуйте что почитать, чтобы также овладеть регулярными выражениями? Спасибо, большое. 
Но появился еще один момент. Повторная очистка убирает rowspan. 
Вставил в пример: http://ideone.com/qJnhO5

Comment: @MaXiM3006, увы, ничего посоветовать не могу, поскольку сам, кроме документации, ничего не читал. Все делаю методом научного тыка, правда, с помощью удобных инструментов:  

    http://regexpr.ru/
    http://regexpal.com/
    http://regex101.com/
    http://phpliveregex.com/

*p.s. исправил опечатку в ответе <$3$1$2> на <$1$2$3>*

@MaXiM3006, теперь повторная очистка не убирает rowspan. Посмотрите пример.

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так?

```
$explanations =  preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?( rowspan=\"\\d+\")?(\/?)>/i",'<$2$1$3>', $explanations);
```

Comment: Спасибо, но нет, не получилось. Также очищает тег, но "rowspan" не остается.
Возможно дело в том что после "td" идет не сразу "rowspan", вот как выглядит тег: <td colspan="1" rowspan="4" style="padding:0px 3px 0px 3px;">

Comment: Да, извините.  

    $explanations =  preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?( rowspan=\"\\d+\")?[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$2$1$3>', $explanations);

Comment: спасибо, но опять нет. очищает вместе с rowspan

Comment: [^>]*? - вот это место, первое вхождение, не понятно, ведь rowspan должен идти до него. А вместо этого вхождения могут идти любые символы (colspan="1" style="padding:0px 3px 0px 3px;")